# PHP Mailer -renaming the files?

Tags: php

I am following a video tutorial in PHP (tutorial not available online for free) which is showing me how to use PHP Mailer. In the phpMailer I downloaded, the files are named, for example, `smtp.php` and `phpMailer.php` but when the author of the tutorial is referring to them in the file path he is putting a `class.` in front of the file name like this

```
includes/phpMailer/class.smtp.php");
```

am I supposed to change the names of the files from `smtp.php` to    `class.smtp.php`, or do I leave the files named the way they are i.e. `smtp.php`, but refer to them in the file path `class.smtp.php`

Can someone please explain

Comment: is the file called class.smtp.php or is it called smtp.php?

Comment: the files in my download is called smtp.php, but the author in the tutorial is writing class.smtp.php in the file path, as explained in OP

Comment: People actually pay money to get explained how to use a mailing class?!

Comment: The video tutorial may be outdated. I would leave the files they were they are and assume they are roughly the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the real filename - i.e. the filename in the `include` or `require` statement must match the name of the actual file..

Answer (score 0):

if you change the name you may run into problems, if in the class it includes the file that you have changed, its ok to change but you will need to scan through all the files and append all the include()'s with the new name :)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the names can run you in trouble. changing **phpMailer.php** to anyname won't affect much as it is the main file that you will be **including** for creating the phpmailer class so if you change the phpMailer.php to class.phpMailer.php or xyz.php just use **include('samename')** and rest are same.

but to rename **smtp.php** to **class.smtp.php** first open **phpMailer.php** and check **line ~460**. You may encounter something link:

```
function SmtpSend($header, $body) {
    include_once($this->PluginDir...
```

there you find the name for **smtp.php**. if its **class.smtp.php** rename your file to **class.smtp.php** or rename it to whatever it is written there...